# append image url dynamically to owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have used owl carousel 2 for product slider. Products are added from the admin panel which needs to be displayed in front-end including images. I am able to add images and call them in the front but it doesn't fit in the owl carousel which creates a messy look on the site. If I directly put it in an image source it works, but calling from Javascript doesn't work.
All I need is that the product info and image should fit within and also owl carousel 2 should be supportive.
I am using jquery 2.1.4 and bootstrap 3.

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="block block-tabs">
            <div class="block-head">
                <div class="block-title">
                    <div class="block-title-text text-lg">best selling</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-tab">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">All</a></li>
                    <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Personalised</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Photo Books</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Calanders</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">LED Lights</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="block-inner">
                <div class="tab-container">
                    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-panel fade in active">
                        <ul id="tab1" class="products kt-owl-carousel" data-margin="20" data-loop="true" data-nav="true" data-responsive='{"0":{"items":1},"600":{"items":3},"1000":{"items":5}}'>

                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-panel fade">
                        <ul class="products kt-owl-carousel" data-margin="20" data-loop="true" data-nav="true" data-responsive='{"0":{"items":1},"600":{"items":3},"1000":{"items":5}}'>
                            <li class="product">
                                <div class="product-container">
                                    <div class="product-left">
                                        <div class="product-thumb">
                                            <a class="product-img" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg" alt="Product"></a>
                                            <a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-right">
                                        <div class="product-name">
                                            <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <span class="product-price">139.98</span>
                                            <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-star">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-button">
                                            <a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>
                                            <a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>
                                            <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product">
                                <div class="product-container">
                                    <div class="product-left">
                                        <div class="product-thumb">
                                            <a class="product-img" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg" alt="Product"></a>
                                            <a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-right">
                                        <div class="product-name">
                                            <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <span class="product-price">139.98</span>
                                            <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-star">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-button">
                                            <a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>
                                            <a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>
                                            <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product">
                                <div class="product-container">
                                    <div class="product-left">
                                        <div class="product-thumb">
                                            <a class="product-img" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg" alt="Product"></a>
                                            <a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-right">
                                        <div class="product-name">
                                            <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <span class="product-price">139.98</span>
                                            <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-star">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-button">
                                            <a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>
                                            <a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>
                                            <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product">
                                <div class="product-container">
                                    <div class="product-left">
                                        <div class="product-thumb">
                                            <a class="product-img" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg" alt="Product"></a>
                                            <a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-right">
                                        <div class="product-name">
                                            <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <span class="product-price">139.98</span>
                                            <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-star">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-button">
                                            <a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>
                                            <a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>
                                            <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="product">
                                <div class="product-container">
                                    <div class="product-left">
                                        <div class="product-thumb">
                                            <a class="product-img" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Mountain_Bluebird.jpg" alt="Product"></a>
                                            <a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-right">
                                        <div class="product-name">
                                            <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price-box">
                                            <span class="product-price">139.98</span>
                                            <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-star">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-button">
                                            <a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>
                                            <a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>
                                            <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    init_carousel();
    var url = '../Home/FrontProduct';
    var data1 = {};
    $.post(url, data1, function (data) {
        OnSuccess(data);
    });
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var All = xml.find("All");
        var AllrowCount = Math.ceil(All.length);
        var content_g = '';
        for (var p = 0; p < AllrowCount; p++) {
            var Allrow = $(All[p]);
            var content = '';
            content = '<div class="item">' +
                      ' <div class="product-container">' +
                      ' <div class="product-left">' +
                      ' <div class="product-thumb">' +
                      ' <a class="product-img" href="#"><img  src="http://ashish81.honestteam.com/products/pro_img/' + Allrow.find("ProductImages").text() + '"></a>' +
                      '<a title="Quick View" href="#" class="btn-quick-view">Quick View</a>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      ' </div>' +
                      '<div class="product-right">' +
                      ' <div class="product-name">' +
                      ' <a href="#">Cotton Lycra Leggings</a>' +
                      '  </div>' +
                      '  <div class="price-box">' +
                      '   <span class="product-price">139.98</span>' +
                      '  <span class="product-price-old">169.00</span>' +
                      '  </div>' +
                      '<div class="product-star">' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' +
                      '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="product-button">' +
                      '<a class="btn-add-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" href="#">Add Wishlist</a>' +
                      '<a class="btn-add-comparre" title="Add to Compare" href="#">Add Compare</a>' +
                      '<a class="button-radius btn-add-cart" title="Add to Cart" href="#">Cart<span class="icon"></span></a>' +
                      '    </div>' +
                      ' </div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '</div>';
            content_g = content_g + content;
        }
        var owl = $('.kt-owl-carousel');
        owl.prepare().trigger('add.owl.carousel', content_g);
    }
});

/* Functions */
function init_carousel() {
    $('.kt-owl-carousel').each(function () {
        var config = $(this).data();
        //config.navText = ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'];
        var animateOut = $(this).data('animateout');
        var animateIn = $(this).data('animatein');

        if (typeof animateOut != 'undefined') {
            config.animateOut = animateOut;
        }
        if (typeof animateIn != 'undefined') {
            config.animateIn = animateIn;
        }
        var owl = $(this);
        owl.owlCarousel(config);
        $(this).find('.owl-item').removeClass('last-item');
        $(this).find('.owl-item.active').last().addClass('last-item');

        var t = $(this);
        owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
            var item = event.item.index;
            t.find('.owl-item').removeClass('last-item');
            setTimeout(function () {
                t.find('.owl-item.active').last().addClass('last-item');
            }, 100);
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy8ubsha/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call the `init` function of `owlcarousel` before you have the content. So, to solve this you have to `initialize` the plugin just after the `ajax` call return.

Something like this:

```js
function ajaxLike() {
$('body').append('<div class="owl-carousel"> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> <div> Your Content </div> </div>');
  // just after the html appears in the DOM you can initialize the owl plugin
  ajaxCallback();
}

// add the html with script, just like you do after the ajax's call return 
ajaxLike();

function ajaxCallback() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10
  });
}
```

```css
.owl-item {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

http://jsbin.com/jetane

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved now. I was calling the init function in the _Layout page and had my script in Index page which was initializing the carousel first. Now the problem is fixed but the only problem is with the star rating, it has disappeared and figuring it. Thanks once again Bro.

Comment: I glad to hear! If you have another question please ask a new one and link it to this one. Good luck!